# automatically update label in Swift by checking the status

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm new to programming with iOS and Swift. I have a label that should automatically be updated when the status of the StreamingKit Framework changes.

Currently the label only changes when I press a different button (it calls the `self.updateView()` function again), but I want it to happen automatically when the status has changed, not by pressing a different button.

Here is the code:

```
func updateView() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    if let label = self.bufferingLabel, let button = self.playerButton{
        if let audioPlayer = self.player{
            if(audioPlayer.state == STKAudioPlayerStateBuffering)
            {
                self.playerState = "Loading"
                button.setImage(self.image1, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            }
            else(audioPlayer.state == STKAudioPlayerStatePlaying)
            {
                self.playerState = self.defaultPlayerState
                self.playerState = "Playing"
                button.setImage(self.image1, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }
        label.text = self.playerState!
    }
}
```

So when I press this button, it gives the first state (which is loading), but after that is done (status changed), the label should change to play, but it doesn't.

```
@IBAction func pressStart(sender: AnyObject) {
    //declare path to streaming
    let filePath = "http://mp3.streampower.be/mnm-high.mp3"

    if player == nil {
        self.player = STKAudioPlayer()
        self.player?.delegate = self
    }
    if let audioPlayer = player{
        if  (audioPlayer.state == STKAudioPlayerStateReady) ||
            (audioPlayer.state == STKAudioPlayerStateStopped){
                audioPlayer.play(filePath)

        }else{
            audioPlayer.stop()
        }
    }
    self.updateView()


}
```

Some of the delegates I tried as well

```
func audioPlayer(audioPlayer: STKAudioPlayer!, didStartPlayingQueueItemId queueItemId: NSObject!) {
    self.updateView()
}

func audioPlayer(audioPlayer: STKAudioPlayer!, didFinishBufferingSourceWithQueueItemId queueItemId: NSObject!) {
    self.updateView()
}


func audioPlayer(audioPlayer: STKAudioPlayer!, stateChanged state: STKAudioPlayerState, previousState: STKAudioPlayerState) {
    self.updateView()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look and use the `delegate` property of the `STKAudioPlayer`.
I'm not familiar with it, but generally in the iOS world, that's how you receive events from an object (the object delegates some stuff to the object of your choice).

Comment: I tried to add the     func audioPlayer(audioPlayer: STKAudioPlayer!, didFinishBufferingSourceWithQueueItemId queueItemId: NSObject!) {
        self.updateView()
    } but it didn't seem to work. Added the delegates I'm using as well to the explanation now, thanks :)

Comment: @SoundShock Did you solve this? If so, could you possibly paste your code? :)

Comment: @awidgery Yes I got it to work, just by adding two lines of code: let sharedPlayer = AppPlayer.sharedInstance.audioPlayer;
            sharedPlayer.delegate = self;
It was a problem with the delegate which wasn't initiated correctly. The other code is all correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSNotifications to send a signal whenever the streaming kit changes. Then you can add an observer to your UI view controller that will trigger a function whenever it receives a signal.

If you want to try out functional reactive programming you can also use The Reactive Cocoa framework to do a similar signal observer pattern.  And finally, there is plain old key-value observation.  One of these options should be able to help you.

Comment: I see what you mean, but for this I need to add yet another API/Framework. I'd rather get the delegate to work, then this isn't necessary, right? But yeah, something goes wrong on that front :) I might do this as a backup plan.

Comment: I tried the NSNotifications, but I can't select player.status, because it is not an AnyObject. Problem is that this is the part in the code I need to check, because it changes the status.